# How to get sequential permutation from a list of items?

Tags: python, list, permutation

i am trying to find a more elegant way to do the following:
I have a list, lets say `[a b c d e f g h i j]`

I want to take permutations of `n` elements, in sequence, without skipping and/or rearranging.
E.g. for `n=2` the required output would be:

```
perm=[[a b], [b c], [c d], [d e], [e f] etc...]
```

or for `n=3`:

```
perm3=[[a b c], [b c d], [c d e], [d e f] etc...]
```

The code i have now is:

```
n = 2
perms = []
input_list = [a b c d e f g h]  
for it in range(0, len(input_list)):
    sliceObj = slice(it, it + n, 1)
    k = input_list[sliceObj]
    if len(k) ==  n:
        perms.append(k)
```

is there something simpler/more elegant?

ANSWER: based on @juanpa.arrivillaga 's answer:

```
perms_n = [input_list[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(input_list)-(n-1))]
```

Thanks again @juanpa.arrivillaga and all

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you have code that works, but are looking for improvements - you should try [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

What you actually want:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-n+1)]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j']]
>>> n=3
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-n+1)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
>>> n = 4
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-n+1)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
>>>
```

So, use the *stop* parameter to your advantage, using `len(x)-n+1`.

<strike>Your code doesn't produce *permutations*, it is a sliding window. In which case, you can make it more elegant. Use the `step` parameter to `range`, pass the slice using indexing syntactic sugar instead of building a slice object explicitly, and use `len(your_list) - 1` as the stop parameter:</strike>

```
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> n = 2
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, n)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
>>> n = 3
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, n)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Note, when `len(seq)` is not divisible by `n`, this might not be the behavior you want. In the above example, with `n=3`, we swallowed the last part because the division has a remainder of 1. Or consider the following:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, n)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
>>> n = 1
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, n)]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i']]
```

In which case, you may want the more strict but also more clunky:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-n+1, n)]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j']]
>>> n = 4
>>> [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x)-n+1, n)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, with the change in the step! 'range(0, len(x)-1, n) should be range(0, len(x)-(n-1))
I'll edit my question! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GSta note my most recent edit, you might prefer the `stop` parameter to take `len(x)-n+1` instead of `len(x)-1`, depending on exactly the behavior you need.

Comment: The output of your code: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]` doesn't match with output in question:  `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'e'], ['e', 'f'], ['f', 'g'], ['g', 'h']]`. Also its not sliding window!

Comment: @bro-grammer ah crap. Yeah.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please remove the remove the text instead of striking.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I had misunderstood the question, this is the correct solution.

```
from itertools import islice

myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

list(zip(*[islice(myList, s, None) for s in range(3)]))

# [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e')]
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer.

Comment: The question was stated wrong as _permutations_, I couldn't realize that it was _sliding window_. Since I am fairly new to StackOverflow what should I do in this case ? Delete my answer or just edit it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

temp = input("Enter the number of elements for a sequence \n")
print(list(permutations(list1, int(temp))))
```

Explanation:

Using permutations of `itertools` we can create sequences

Get the number of elements for a sequence

```
temp = input("Enter the number of elements for a sequence \n")
```

print the sequences

```
print(list(permutations(list1, int(temp))))
```

Output:
For temp:2

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('a', 'g'), ('a', 'h'), ('a', 'i'), ('a', 'j'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('b', 'h'), ('b', 'i'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('c', 'g'), ('c', 'h'), ('c', 'i'), ('c', 'j'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'), ('d', 'g'), ('d', 'h'), ('d', 'i'), ('d', 'j'), ('e', 'a'), ('e', 'b'), ('e', 'c'), ('e', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('e', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('e', 'i'), ('e', 'j'), ('f', 'a'), ('f', 'b'), ('f', 'c'), ('f', 'd'), ('f', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('f', 'i'), ('f', 'j'), ('g', 'a'), ('g', 'b'), ('g', 'c'), ('g', 'd'), ('g', 'e'), ('g', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('g', 'i'), ('g', 'j'), ('h', 'a'), ('h', 'b'), ('h', 'c'), ('h', 'd'), ('h', 'e'), ('h', 'f'), ('h', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('h', 'j'), ('i', 'a'), ('i', 'b'), ('i', 'c'), ('i', 'd'), ('i', 'e'), ('i', 'f'), ('i', 'g'), ('i', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('j', 'a'), ('j', 'b'), ('j', 'c'), ('j', 'd'), ('j', 'e'), ('j', 'f'), ('j', 'g'), ('j', 'h'), ('j', 'i')]
```

For temp : 3

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'h'), ('a', 'b', 'i'), ('a', 'b', 'j'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'h'), ('a', 'c', 'i'), ('a', 'c', 'j'), ('a', 'd', 'b'), ('a', 'd', 'c'), ('a', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'g'), ('a', 'd', 'h'), ('a', 'd', 'i'), ('a', 'd', 'j'), ('a', 'e', 'b'), ('a', 'e', 'c'), ('a', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'e', 'g'), ('a', 'e', 'h'), ('a', 'e', 'i'), ('a', 'e', 'j'), ('a', 'f', 'b'), ('a', 'f', 'c'), ('a', 'f', 'd'), ('a', 'f', 'e'), ('a', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'f', 'h'), ('a', 'f', 'i'), ('a', 'f', 'j'), ('a', 'g', 'b'), ('a', 'g', 'c'), ('a', 'g', 'd'), ('a', 'g', 'e'), ('a', 'g', 'f'), ('a', 'g', 'h'), ('a', 'g', 'i'), ('a', 'g', 'j'), ('a', 'h', 'b'), ('a', 'h', 'c'), ('a', 'h', 'd'), ('a', 'h', 'e'), ('a', 'h', 'f'), ('a', 'h', 'g'), ('a', 'h', 'i'), ('a', 'h', 'j'), ('a', 'i', 'b'), ('a', 'i', 'c'), ('a', 'i', 'd'), ('a', 'i', 'e'), ('a', 'i', 'f'), ('a', 'i', 'g'), ('a', 'i', 'h'), ('a', 'i', 'j'), ('a', 'j', 'b'), ('a', 'j', 'c'), ('a', 'j', 'd'), ('a', 'j', 'e'), ('a', 'j', 'f'), ('a', 'j', 'g'), ('a', 'j', 'h'), ('a', 'j', 'i'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'd'), ('b', 'a', 'e'), ('b', 'a', 'f'), ('b', 'a', 'g'), ('b', 'a', 'h'), ('b', 'a', 'i'), ('b', 'a', 'j'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'g'), ('b', 'c', 'h'), ('b', 'c', 'i'), ('b', 'c', 'j'), ('b', 'd', 'a'), ('b', 'd', 'c'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'h'), ('b', 'd', 'i'), ('b', 'd', 'j'), ('b', 'e', 'a'), ('b', 'e', 'c'), ('b', 'e', 'd'), ('b', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'e', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('b', 'e', 'i'), ('b', 'e', 'j'), ('b', 'f', 'a'), ('b', 'f', 'c'), ('b', 'f', 'd'), ('b', 'f', 'e'), ('b', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'f', 'h'), ('b', 'f', 'i'), ('b', 'f', 'j'), ('b', 'g', 'a'), ('b', 'g', 'c'), ('b', 'g', 'd'), ('b', 'g', 'e'), ('b', 'g', 'f'), ('b', 'g', 'h'), ('b', 'g', 'i'), ('b', 'g', 'j'), ('b', 'h', 'a'), ('b', 'h', 'c'), ('b', 'h', 'd'), ('b', 'h', 'e'), ('b', 'h', 'f'), ('b', 'h', 'g'), ('b', 'h', 'i'), ('b', 'h', 'j'), ('b', 'i', 'a'), ('b', 'i', 'c'), ('b', 'i', 'd'), ('b', 'i', 'e'), ('b', 'i', 'f'), ('b', 'i', 'g'), ('b', 'i', 'h'), ('b', 'i', 'j'), ('b', 'j', 'a'), ('b', 'j', 'c'), ('b', 'j', 'd'), ('b', 'j', 'e'), ('b', 'j', 'f'), ('b', 'j', 'g'), ('b', 'j', 'h'), ('b', 'j', 'i'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'd'), ('c', 'a', 'e'), ('c', 'a', 'f'), ('c', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 'h'), ('c', 'a', 'i'), ('c', 'a', 'j'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'd'), ('c', 'b', 'e'), ('c', 'b', 'f'), ('c', 'b', 'g'), ('c', 'b', 'h'), ('c', 'b', 'i'), ('c', 'b', 'j'), ('c', 'd', 'a'), ('c', 'd', 'b'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('c', 'd', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'h'), ('c', 'd', 'i'), ('c', 'd', 'j'), ('c', 'e', 'a'), ('c', 'e', 'b'), ('c', 'e', 'd'), ('c', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'e', 'g'), ('c', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'e', 'i'), ('c', 'e', 'j'), ('c', 'f', 'a'), ('c', 'f', 'b'), ('c', 'f', 'd'), ('c', 'f', 'e'), ('c', 'f', 'g'), ('c', 'f', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i'), ('c', 'f', 'j'), ('c', 'g', 'a'), ('c', 'g', 'b'), ('c', 'g', 'd'), ('c', 'g', 'e'), ('c', 'g', 'f'), ('c', 'g', 'h'), ('c', 'g', 'i'), ('c', 'g', 'j'), ('c', 'h', 'a'), ('c', 'h', 'b'), ('c', 'h', 'd'), ('c', 'h', 'e'), ('c', 'h', 'f'), ('c', 'h', 'g'), ('c', 'h', 'i'), ('c', 'h', 'j'), ('c', 'i', 'a'), ('c', 'i', 'b'), ('c', 'i', 'd'), ('c', 'i', 'e'), ('c', 'i', 'f'), ('c', 'i', 'g'), ('c', 'i', 'h'), ('c', 'i', 'j'), ('c', 'j', 'a'), ('c', 'j', 'b'), ('c', 'j', 'd'), ('c', 'j', 'e'), ('c', 'j', 'f'), ('c', 'j', 'g'), ('c', 'j', 'h'), ('c', 'j', 'i'), ('d', 'a', 'b'), ('d', 'a', 'c'), ('d', 'a', 'e'), ('d', 'a', 'f'), ('d', 'a', 'g'), ('d', 'a', 'h'), ('d', 'a', 'i'), ('d', 'a', 'j'), ('d', 'b', 'a'), ('d', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'b', 'e'), ('d', 'b', 'f'), ('d', 'b', 'g'), ('d', 'b', 'h'), ('d', 'b', 'i'), ('d', 'b', 'j'), ('d', 'c', 'a'), ('d', 'c', 'b'), ('d', 'c', 'e'), ('d', 'c', 'f'), ('d', 'c', 'g'), ('d', 'c', 'h'), ('d', 'c', 'i'), ('d', 'c', 'j'), ('d', 'e', 'a'), ('d', 'e', 'b'), ('d', 'e', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('d', 'e', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'h'), ('d', 'e', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'j'), ('d', 'f', 'a'), ('d', 'f', 'b'), ('d', 'f', 'c'), ('d', 'f', 'e'), ('d', 'f', 'g'), ('d', 'f', 'h'), ('d', 'f', 'i'), ('d', 'f', 'j'), ('d', 'g', 'a'), ('d', 'g', 'b'), ('d', 'g', 'c'), ('d', 'g', 'e'), ('d', 'g', 'f'), ('d', 'g', 'h'), ('d', 'g', 'i'), ('d', 'g', 'j'), ('d', 'h', 'a'), ('d', 'h', 'b'), ('d', 'h', 'c'), ('d', 'h', 'e'), ('d', 'h', 'f'), ('d', 'h', 'g'), ('d', 'h', 'i'), ('d', 'h', 'j'), ('d', 'i', 'a'), ('d', 'i', 'b'), ('d', 'i', 'c'), ('d', 'i', 'e'), ('d', 'i', 'f'), ('d', 'i', 'g'), ('d', 'i', 'h'), ('d', 'i', 'j'), ('d', 'j', 'a'), ('d', 'j', 'b'), ('d', 'j', 'c'), ('d', 'j', 'e'), ('d', 'j', 'f'), ('d', 'j', 'g'), ('d', 'j', 'h'), ('d', 'j', 'i'), ('e', 'a', 'b'), ('e', 'a', 'c'), ('e', 'a', 'd'), ('e', 'a', 'f'), ('e', 'a', 'g'), ('e', 'a', 'h'), ('e', 'a', 'i'), ('e', 'a', 'j'), ('e', 'b', 'a'), ('e', 'b', 'c'), ('e', 'b', 'd'), ('e', 'b', 'f'), ('e', 'b', 'g'), ('e', 'b', 'h'), ('e', 'b', 'i'), ('e', 'b', 'j'), ('e', 'c', 'a'), ('e', 'c', 'b'), ('e', 'c', 'd'), ('e', 'c', 'f'), ('e', 'c', 'g'), ('e', 'c', 'h'), ('e', 'c', 'i'), ('e', 'c', 'j'), ('e', 'd', 'a'), ('e', 'd', 'b'), ('e', 'd', 'c'), ('e', 'd', 'f'), ('e', 'd', 'g'), ('e', 'd', 'h'), ('e', 'd', 'i'), ('e', 'd', 'j'), ('e', 'f', 'a'), ('e', 'f', 'b'), ('e', 'f', 'c'), ('e', 'f', 'd'), ('e', 'f', 'g'), ('e', 'f', 'h'), ('e', 'f', 'i'), ('e', 'f', 'j'), ('e', 'g', 'a'), ('e', 'g', 'b'), ('e', 'g', 'c'), ('e', 'g', 'd'), ('e', 'g', 'f'), ('e', 'g', 'h'), ('e', 'g', 'i'), ('e', 'g', 'j'), ('e', 'h', 'a'), ('e', 'h', 'b'), ('e', 'h', 'c'), ('e', 'h', 'd'), ('e', 'h', 'f'), ('e', 'h', 'g'), ('e', 'h', 'i'), ('e', 'h', 'j'), ('e', 'i', 'a'), ('e', 'i', 'b'), ('e', 'i', 'c'), ('e', 'i', 'd'), ('e', 'i', 'f'), ('e', 'i', 'g'), ('e', 'i', 'h'), ('e', 'i', 'j'), ('e', 'j', 'a'), ('e', 'j', 'b'), ('e', 'j', 'c'), ('e', 'j', 'd'), ('e', 'j', 'f'), ('e', 'j', 'g'), ('e', 'j', 'h'), ('e', 'j', 'i'), ('f', 'a', 'b'), ('f', 'a', 'c'), ('f', 'a', 'd'), ('f', 'a', 'e'), ('f', 'a', 'g'), ('f', 'a', 'h'), ('f', 'a', 'i'), ('f', 'a', 'j'), ('f', 'b', 'a'), ('f', 'b', 'c'), ('f', 'b', 'd'), ('f', 'b', 'e'), ('f', 'b', 'g'), ('f', 'b', 'h'), ('f', 'b', 'i'), ('f', 'b', 'j'), ('f', 'c', 'a'), ('f', 'c', 'b'), ('f', 'c', 'd'), ('f', 'c', 'e'), ('f', 'c', 'g'), ('f', 'c', 'h'), ('f', 'c', 'i'), ('f', 'c', 'j'), ('f', 'd', 'a'), ('f', 'd', 'b'), ('f', 'd', 'c'), ('f', 'd', 'e'), ('f', 'd', 'g'), ('f', 'd', 'h'), ('f', 'd', 'i'), ('f', 'd', 'j'), ('f', 'e', 'a'), ('f', 'e', 'b'), ('f', 'e', 'c'), ('f', 'e', 'd'), ('f', 'e', 'g'), ('f', 'e', 'h'), ('f', 'e', 'i'), ('f', 'e', 'j'), ('f', 'g', 'a'), ('f', 'g', 'b'), ('f', 'g', 'c'), ('f', 'g', 'd'), ('f', 'g', 'e'), ('f', 'g', 'h'), ('f', 'g', 'i'), ('f', 'g', 'j'), ('f', 'h', 'a'), ('f', 'h', 'b'), ('f', 'h', 'c'), ('f', 'h', 'd'), ('f', 'h', 'e'), ('f', 'h', 'g'), ('f', 'h', 'i'), ('f', 'h', 'j'), ('f', 'i', 'a'), ('f', 'i', 'b'), ('f', 'i', 'c'), ('f', 'i', 'd'), ('f', 'i', 'e'), ('f', 'i', 'g'), ('f', 'i', 'h'), ('f', 'i', 'j'), ('f', 'j', 'a'), ('f', 'j', 'b'), ('f', 'j', 'c'), ('f', 'j', 'd'), ('f', 'j', 'e'), ('f', 'j', 'g'), ('f', 'j', 'h'), ('f', 'j', 'i'), ('g', 'a', 'b'), ('g', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 'd'), ('g', 'a', 'e'), ('g', 'a', 'f'), ('g', 'a', 'h'), ('g', 'a', 'i'), ('g', 'a', 'j'), ('g', 'b', 'a'), ('g', 'b', 'c'), ('g', 'b', 'd'), ('g', 'b', 'e'), ('g', 'b', 'f'), ('g', 'b', 'h'), ('g', 'b', 'i'), ('g', 'b', 'j'), ('g', 'c', 'a'), ('g', 'c', 'b'), ('g', 'c', 'd'), ('g', 'c', 'e'), ('g', 'c', 'f'), ('g', 'c', 'h'), ('g', 'c', 'i'), ('g', 'c', 'j'), ('g', 'd', 'a'), ('g', 'd', 'b'), ('g', 'd', 'c'), ('g', 'd', 'e'), ('g', 'd', 'f'), ('g', 'd', 'h'), ('g', 'd', 'i'), ('g', 'd', 'j'), ('g', 'e', 'a'), ('g', 'e', 'b'), ('g', 'e', 'c'), ('g', 'e', 'd'), ('g', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'e', 'h'), ('g', 'e', 'i'), ('g', 'e', 'j'), ('g', 'f', 'a'), ('g', 'f', 'b'), ('g', 'f', 'c'), ('g', 'f', 'd'), ('g', 'f', 'e'), ('g', 'f', 'h'), ('g', 'f', 'i'), ('g', 'f', 'j'), ('g', 'h', 'a'), ('g', 'h', 'b'), ('g', 'h', 'c'), ('g', 'h', 'd'), ('g', 'h', 'e'), ('g', 'h', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('g', 'h', 'j'), ('g', 'i', 'a'), ('g', 'i', 'b'), ('g', 'i', 'c'), ('g', 'i', 'd'), ('g', 'i', 'e'), ('g', 'i', 'f'), ('g', 'i', 'h'), ('g', 'i', 'j'), ('g', 'j', 'a'), ('g', 'j', 'b'), ('g', 'j', 'c'), ('g', 'j', 'd'), ('g', 'j', 'e'), ('g', 'j', 'f'), ('g', 'j', 'h'), ('g', 'j', 'i'), ('h', 'a', 'b'), ('h', 'a', 'c'), ('h', 'a', 'd'), ('h', 'a', 'e'), ('h', 'a', 'f'), ('h', 'a', 'g'), ('h', 'a', 'i'), ('h', 'a', 'j'), ('h', 'b', 'a'), ('h', 'b', 'c'), ('h', 'b', 'd'), ('h', 'b', 'e'), ('h', 'b', 'f'), ('h', 'b', 'g'), ('h', 'b', 'i'), ('h', 'b', 'j'), ('h', 'c', 'a'), ('h', 'c', 'b'), ('h', 'c', 'd'), ('h', 'c', 'e'), ('h', 'c', 'f'), ('h', 'c', 'g'), ('h', 'c', 'i'), ('h', 'c', 'j'), ('h', 'd', 'a'), ('h', 'd', 'b'), ('h', 'd', 'c'), ('h', 'd', 'e'), ('h', 'd', 'f'), ('h', 'd', 'g'), ('h', 'd', 'i'), ('h', 'd', 'j'), ('h', 'e', 'a'), ('h', 'e', 'b'), ('h', 'e', 'c'), ('h', 'e', 'd'), ('h', 'e', 'f'), ('h', 'e', 'g'), ('h', 'e', 'i'), ('h', 'e', 'j'), ('h', 'f', 'a'), ('h', 'f', 'b'), ('h', 'f', 'c'), ('h', 'f', 'd'), ('h', 'f', 'e'), ('h', 'f', 'g'), ('h', 'f', 'i'), ('h', 'f', 'j'), ('h', 'g', 'a'), ('h', 'g', 'b'), ('h', 'g', 'c'), ('h', 'g', 'd'), ('h', 'g', 'e'), ('h', 'g', 'f'), ('h', 'g', 'i'), ('h', 'g', 'j'), ('h', 'i', 'a'), ('h', 'i', 'b'), ('h', 'i', 'c'), ('h', 'i', 'd'), ('h', 'i', 'e'), ('h', 'i', 'f'), ('h', 'i', 'g'), ('h', 'i', 'j'), ('h', 'j', 'a'), ('h', 'j', 'b'), ('h', 'j', 'c'), ('h', 'j', 'd'), ('h', 'j', 'e'), ('h', 'j', 'f'), ('h', 'j', 'g'), ('h', 'j', 'i'), ('i', 'a', 'b'), ('i', 'a', 'c'), ('i', 'a', 'd'), ('i', 'a', 'e'), ('i', 'a', 'f'), ('i', 'a', 'g'), ('i', 'a', 'h'), ('i', 'a', 'j'), ('i', 'b', 'a'), ('i', 'b', 'c'), ('i', 'b', 'd'), ('i', 'b', 'e'), ('i', 'b', 'f'), ('i', 'b', 'g'), ('i', 'b', 'h'), ('i', 'b', 'j'), ('i', 'c', 'a'), ('i', 'c', 'b'), ('i', 'c', 'd'), ('i', 'c', 'e'), ('i', 'c', 'f'), ('i', 'c', 'g'), ('i', 'c', 'h'), ('i', 'c', 'j'), ('i', 'd', 'a'), ('i', 'd', 'b'), ('i', 'd', 'c'), ('i', 'd', 'e'), ('i', 'd', 'f'), ('i', 'd', 'g'), ('i', 'd', 'h'), ('i', 'd', 'j'), ('i', 'e', 'a'), ('i', 'e', 'b'), ('i', 'e', 'c'), ('i', 'e', 'd'), ('i', 'e', 'f'), ('i', 'e', 'g'), ('i', 'e', 'h'), ('i', 'e', 'j'), ('i', 'f', 'a'), ('i', 'f', 'b'), ('i', 'f', 'c'), ('i', 'f', 'd'), ('i', 'f', 'e'), ('i', 'f', 'g'), ('i', 'f', 'h'), ('i', 'f', 'j'), ('i', 'g', 'a'), ('i', 'g', 'b'), ('i', 'g', 'c'), ('i', 'g', 'd'), ('i', 'g', 'e'), ('i', 'g', 'f'), ('i', 'g', 'h'), ('i', 'g', 'j'), ('i', 'h', 'a'), ('i', 'h', 'b'), ('i', 'h', 'c'), ('i', 'h', 'd'), ('i', 'h', 'e'), ('i', 'h', 'f'), ('i', 'h', 'g'), ('i', 'h', 'j'), ('i', 'j', 'a'), ('i', 'j', 'b'), ('i', 'j', 'c'), ('i', 'j', 'd'), ('i', 'j', 'e'), ('i', 'j', 'f'), ('i', 'j', 'g'), ('i', 'j', 'h'), ('j', 'a', 'b'), ('j', 'a', 'c'), ('j', 'a', 'd'), ('j', 'a', 'e'), ('j', 'a', 'f'), ('j', 'a', 'g'), ('j', 'a', 'h'), ('j', 'a', 'i'), ('j', 'b', 'a'), ('j', 'b', 'c'), ('j', 'b', 'd'), ('j', 'b', 'e'), ('j', 'b', 'f'), ('j', 'b', 'g'), ('j', 'b', 'h'), ('j', 'b', 'i'), ('j', 'c', 'a'), ('j', 'c', 'b'), ('j', 'c', 'd'), ('j', 'c', 'e'), ('j', 'c', 'f'), ('j', 'c', 'g'), ('j', 'c', 'h'), ('j', 'c', 'i'), ('j', 'd', 'a'), ('j', 'd', 'b'), ('j', 'd', 'c'), ('j', 'd', 'e'), ('j', 'd', 'f'), ('j', 'd', 'g'), ('j', 'd', 'h'), ('j', 'd', 'i'), ('j', 'e', 'a'), ('j', 'e', 'b'), ('j', 'e', 'c'), ('j', 'e', 'd'), ('j', 'e', 'f'), ('j', 'e', 'g'), ('j', 'e', 'h'), ('j', 'e', 'i'), ('j', 'f', 'a'), ('j', 'f', 'b'), ('j', 'f', 'c'), ('j', 'f', 'd'), ('j', 'f', 'e'), ('j', 'f', 'g'), ('j', 'f', 'h'), ('j', 'f', 'i'), ('j', 'g', 'a'), ('j', 'g', 'b'), ('j', 'g', 'c'), ('j', 'g', 'd'), ('j', 'g', 'e'), ('j', 'g', 'f'), ('j', 'g', 'h'), ('j', 'g', 'i'), ('j', 'h', 'a'), ('j', 'h', 'b'), ('j', 'h', 'c'), ('j', 'h', 'd'), ('j', 'h', 'e'), ('j', 'h', 'f'), ('j', 'h', 'g'), ('j', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'i', 'a'), ('j', 'i', 'b'), ('j', 'i', 'c'), ('j', 'i', 'd'), ('j', 'i', 'e'), ('j', 'i', 'f'), ('j', 'i', 'g'), ('j', 'i', 'h')]
```

Comment: @theausome: Actually while I am answering I didn't refresh the page. so  I am not aware that it is already submitted

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `itertools`,

```
import itertools

def window(iterable, size):
     values = [itertools.islice(iterable, s, None) for s in xrange(size)]
     return itertools.izip(*values)
```

**Results**

```
In [38]: print list(window(x,2))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('f', 'g'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'i'), ('i', 'j')]

In [39]: print list(window(x,3))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('e', 'f', 'g'), ('f', 'g', 'h'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('h', 'i', 'j')]

In [40]: print list(window(x,5))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'), ('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')]
```